# how to unlist my images list while keeping their dimensions?

Tags: r

I'm new to R, i want to know if Iam reading images using readJPEG and it works, but gives me a list with one column, each row contains a 10*10 inside, the problem is I cant do operations on, because it's a list, i.e calculating the euclidean distance between images using "dist". how can I convert it to a matrix with the same dimensions without using "unlist"???

Answer (score 0):

Try `do.call("rbind",thelistobject)`.